# Schur positivity of a polynomial

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, characters, unitary-representations, symmetric-polynomials

Suppose a polynomial of the form
$$\prod_i^d \sum_j^p x_i^{f_j}$$
clearly symmetric, where $f_j\in \mathbb{N}$. There is a way to find the set of $f$ numbers such that this polynomial is Schur positive? I have been trying to build a Kashiwara crystal and impose conditions on the weight function but without success beyond the fact that $\lbrace f_0,...,f_p\rbrace$ must be a sequence of consecutive numbers so $f_{i+1}= f_{i}+1 \text{ or } f_{i+1}= f_{i}, i<p$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given $f_1,\dots,f_p$ and $d\geq \max f_i$, a necessary and sufficient condition is that all zeros of the polynomial $\sum x^{f_j}$ are real. See *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2, Exercise 7.91. **Note.** Your necessary condition need not hold for small $d$. If $d=1$, then $\sum x_1^{f_j}= \sum s_{f_j}(x_1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been struggling with this problem for a while and this answer is just what I was looking for. Regarding the condition $d\geq max f_i$, where this come from?

Comment: You need the Schur functions $s_\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_d)$ to be linearly independent when $\lambda$ is a partition of $n\leq \max f_j$. This is equivalent to $d\geq \max f_j$.

Comment: @RichardStanley Can you please take a look at my question here, based on a remark you made in one of your papers? https://mathoverflow.net/q/392279/5017

Answer (score 0):

A similar case which I know about are the [Boolean symmetric functions](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Epeal/polynomials/booleanProductPolynomials.htm),
introduced by L. Billera, S. Billey, and V. Tewari.
They prove Schur positivity by using *Chern plethysm*, which I do not know much about. It is still open to to explain combinatorially the coefficients of the Schur expansion of the boolean symmetric functions.

Comment: I don't see why Boolean symmetric functions are a special case.

Comment: Ah, now I see - each inner sum only depends on one variable. Yes, its different. It was the unusual $\prod \sum$-form that triggered the memory, and perhaps still one can find some other connection...